# How to achieve a sorted but random list with javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, random, filter

I currently use this code to randomly sort my list of items and it works quite well:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
(function ($) {
    $.fn.randomize = function (childElem) {
        return this.each(function () {
            var $this = $(this);
            var elems = $this.children(childElem);
            elems.sort(function () {
                return (Math.round(Math.random()) - 0.5);
            });
            $this.remove(childElem);
            for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++)
            $this.append(elems[i]);
        });
    };
})(jQuery);

(function ($) {
    if (window.location.href.indexOf("st=") > -1) {

    } else {
        $('#itemBlock').randomize('.list_1');
    }
})(jQuery);

});
```

However, I am stumped when it comes to figuring out a way to modify this script to randomly return results in a certain order. For instance, the list I use this with returns all of a specific type of item from all of 5 stores. So if someone is looking for an apron it will show all of the aprons we have at each of our 5 stores.

The code above surely randomizes the list, but I don't know how to take into account the store location.

So right now a search for aprons would initially return from stores A, B, C, D, and E a list like this:

BCDAEBCDDDCEABBACACABCDAA

But what we want to achieve is a return like this:

ABCDEABCDEABCDEABCDEABCDE

Not necessarily in exactly that order but someway to modify the function so that a result from each store is loaded before more results are loaded. So there wouldn't be 3 in a row from one store, or one store would be represented more than others.

Do I go about this by using the filter or sort function? Or would pure javascript handle this more efficiently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve this, you would have to follow the following steps:

1. Randomly sort the items from each store individually
2. Number the items in each randomised list
3. OPTIONAL - if you want the stores in order, pad the number with zeros and append an identifier for the store (`[padded item number]|[store identifier]` eg `00001|A`)
4. Combine all the lists into one
5. Sort this new list by the ordered number (or string)

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! I've been working on it for awhile without much headway--I think I understand though. I randomly sort the individual lists--got it--then I number them in order, then in the combined list I set it up so it is sorted in order: all the 1s, then 2s, then 3s etc. This is a clever solution. I have a bit of work to do on the code but I appreciate your perspective! Wouldn't have occurred to me! If I don't have direct access to the individual lists, would there be a way to assign numbers still? If I'm only dealing with the combined list?

Comment: You could group the elements somehow. Otherwise loop through and keep track in an array which number you are on for each store.

Comment: Hmmm...got it. Gonna give a few things a try then. I think if I use javscript I should be able to identify each of the stores.